# Magento 1 sql query for products with custom attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Need sql query which get products attributes including custom attributes like following:
product_id,product_type,sku,Product_Name,Brand,Color,Size,Price,Special_Price,inventory_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the query for my problem you can get hint from the following query and modify it as per your requirements(update attributed ids as per your Database):

```
SELECT 
    e.entity_id AS product_id,
    e.type_id AS product_type,
    e.sku AS sku,
    j.value AS Product_Name,
    mB.value AS Brand,
    mc.value AS Color,
    mcs.value AS Size,
    p1.value AS Price,
    ps1.value AS Special_Price,
    itV.value AS inventory_type,
    CASE
        WHEN s.value = '1' THEN 'Enabled'
        WHEN s.value = '2' THEN 'Disabled'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS product_status
FROM
    catalog_product_entity AS e
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS it ON it.attribute_id = 241
        AND it.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND it.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = it.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    eav_attribute_option_value itV ON itV.option_id = it.value
        AND itV.STORE_ID = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_text AS si ON si.attribute_id = 133
        AND si.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND si.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = si.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS j ON j.attribute_id = 71
        AND j.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND j.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = j.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS spsk ON spsk.attribute_id = 168
        AND spsk.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND spsk.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = spsk.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS s ON s.attribute_id = 96
        AND s.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND s.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = s.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS m ON m.attribute_id = 81
        AND m.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND m.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = m.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    eav_attribute_option_value mB ON mB.option_id = m.value
        AND mB.STORE_ID = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS clm ON clm.attribute_id = 92
        AND clm.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND clm.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = clm.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    eav_attribute_option_value mc ON mc.option_id = clm.value
        AND mc.STORE_ID = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS cls ON cls.attribute_id = 148
        AND cls.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND cls.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = cls.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    eav_attribute_option_value mcs ON mcs.option_id = clm.value
        AND mcs.STORE_ID = 0
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal p1 ON p1.attribute_id = 75
        AND m.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND m.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = p1.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal ps1 ON ps1.attribute_id = 76
        AND m.entity_type_id = '4'
        AND m.STORE_ID = 0
        AND e.entity_id = ps1.entity_id
WHERE
    s.value = 1
```